# Unable to reference MongoDB document fields inside case statements while using $eq operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My MongoDB version is 3.6.3

An example of my collection:

```
/*A snippet of my collection*/
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a81a0de19a4ea2a8b119baa"),
    "Site" : 123,
    "Event" : "AnEvent",
    "SubEvent" : "MoreDetails",
    "Level" : 2
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a81a0de19a4ea2a8b119bab"),
    "Site" : 456,
    "Event" : "TheEvent",
    "SubEvent" : "FurtherDetails",
    "Level" : 3
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a81a0de19a4ea2a8b119bac"),
    "Site" : 789,
    "Event" : "WorldEndingEvent",
    "SubEvent" : "RelevantDetails",
    "Level" : 5
}
```

I am trying to output the following document (Add a new field conditionally based on the Event and SubEvent fields):

```
/*Desired output of query*/
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a81a0de19a4ea2a8b119baa"),
    "Site" : 123,
    "Event" : "AnEvent",
    "SubEvent" : "MoreDetails",
    "Level" : 2,
    "NewLevel": 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a81a0de19a4ea2a8b119bab"),
    "Site" : 456,
    "Event" : "TheEvent",
    "SubEvent" : "FurtherDetails",
    "Level" : 3,
    "NewLevel": 2
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a81a0de19a4ea2a8b119bac"),
    "Site" : 789,
    "Event" : "WorldEndingEvent",
    "SubEvent" : "RelevantDetails",
    "Level" : 5,
    "NewLevel": 4
}
```

To achieve this, I am using the switch case construct provided by MongoDB (but with no success):

```
/*This does not work as Mongo does not recognize $Event in case statement*/
db.getCollection('Error_events_aggregated').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            Site: 1,
            Event: 1,
            SubEvent: 1,
            Level: 1,
            NewLevel: {
                $switch: {
                    branches: [
                        {
                            case: {$and: [
                                          {"$Event": {$eq: "AnEvent"}},
                                          {"$SubEvent": {$eq: "MoreDetails"}}
                                          ]},
                            then: 1
                        },
                        {
                            case: {$and: [
                                          {"$Event": {$eq: "TheEvent"}},
                                          {"$SubEvent": {$eq: "FurtherDetails"}}
                                          ]},
                            then: 2
                        },
                        {
                            case: {$and: [
                                          {"$Event": {$eq: "WorldEndingEvent"}},
                                          {"$SubEvent": {$eq: "RelevantDetails"}}
                                          ]},
                            then: 4
                        }
                    ],
                    default: "$Level"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
])
```

This doesn't work as MongoDB is not able to recognize $Event.

However, if I use a similar method (projection based on switch case) but using $gt (and similar) operators, then MongoDB doesn't have any problems identifying $Event...

```
/*This works. Mongo recognizes $Event now, inside the case statement*/
db.getCollection('Error_events_aggregated').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            Site: 1,
            Event: 1,
            SubEvent: 1,
            Level: 1,
            NewLevel: {
                $switch: {
                    branches: [
                        {
                            case: {$gt: ["$Event", "V"]}, /*Matches WorldEndingEvent*/
                            then: 4 
                        },
                        {
                            case: {$gt: ["$Event", "S"]}, /*Matches TheEvent*/
                            then: 2
                        },
                        {
                            case: {$gt: ["$Event", "Am"]}, /*Matches AnEvent*/
                            then: 1
                        }
                    ],
                    default: "$Level"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
])
```

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing incorrectly? I tried reading through the docs, but all examples related to $switch as well as $cond cover only $gt and similar operators and doesn't cover equality-based operations.

I have tried using the {:} syntax for checking equality as well, but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) instead of `$project`. Also the syntax for `$switch` with `$eq` is quite different here, try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            NewLevel: {
                $switch: {
                    branches: [
                        {
                            case: {
                                $and: [
                                    { $eq: [ "$Event", "AnEvent" ] },
                                    { $eq: [ "$SubEvent", "MoreDetails" ] }
                                ] 
                            },
                            then: 1
                        },
                        {
                            case: {
                                $and: [
                                    { $eq: [ "$Event", "TheEvent" ] },
                                    { $eq: [ "$SubEvent", "FurtherDetails" ] }
                                ] 
                            },
                            then: 2
                        },
                        {
                            case: {
                                $and: [
                                    { $eq: [ "$Event", "WorldEndingEvent" ] },
                                    { $eq: [ "$SubEvent", "RelevantDetails" ] }
                                ] 
                            },
                            then: 4
                        }
                    ],
                    default: "$Level"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Brilliant! That worked. Thanks a million! :) I wonder why I couldn't find the alternate syntax anywhere in the documentation though... Might be there, but not referenced in an easy-to-find place.

Answer (score 2):

Switch statement in mongoDB basically evaluates series of case EXPRESSIONS,so anything included in a case statement should be a expression and not just a variable name.Yes,we can use $eq(Equal operator in mongDB) instead of $gt

```
db.getCollection('Error_events_aggregated').aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        Site: 1,
        Event: 1,
        SubEvent: 1,
        Level: 1,
        NewLevel: {
            $switch: {
                branches: [
                    {
                        case: {$eq: ["$Event", "WorldEndingEvent"]}, /*Matches WorldEndingEvent*/
                        then: 4 
                    },
                    {
                        case: {$eq: ["$Event", "TheEvent"]}, /*Matches TheEvent*/
                        then: 2
                    },
                    {
                        case: {$eq: ["$Event", "AnEvent"]}, /*Matches AnEvent*/
                        then: 1
                    }
                ],
                default: "$Level"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Please let me know if this works fine and if there are any other changes to be made.